# HP Laserjet 1018 paper jam on output

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet, paper

The issue is a constant jam on output, the paper exit the fuser and stops just 3 mm before the sheet is released by the fuser. I don't know what causes this problem:

- The paper gets stuck on the heater roller of the printer.
- I checked the heater roller, it's working fine.
- When the transfer roller transfers the page, page comes out a little and then jam.

I cleaned the heater assembly and the transfer roller but the problem persists.

Comment: What research have you done? HP has a rather comprehensive troubleshooting information on their [support site](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-laserjet-1018-printer/1814092/troubleshooting).

Comment: yes i have read it , it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: When you say it gets "*stuck on the heater*", is it actually adhered to it?

Comment: Also, have the separation pad and pickup roller ever been changed? These are items that wear and cause the common paper mis-feed and jams.

Comment: it just stuck , seems that the heater roller stops but its working fine, and the paper feed is Ok.

Comment: Please define *stuck*. Is it stuck like tape or glue?

Comment: It stuks , like its pushed hard form the back and looks that the heater roller stops, but every thing is working.

Comment: What kind of paper are you using? This can happen if you use paper designed for inkjet printers.

Comment: how do i know that the paper is for leserjet printer?

Comment: Does this happens because of the gears of heater roller?

Comment: What does the wrapping of the paper say? It normally tells you whether the paper is for laser or inkjet. If it says "photo paper", it is almost certainly for inkjet. Inkjet paper has a coating designed to absorb the ink. That coating can come of, and get stuck inside the fuser, because of the heat generated by the fuser.

Comment: I am using BLC Papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fuser film.

> It was not rotating by the heater roller because it tear form the
>   right side.

replaced it solves the problem.

[image: fuser film]